# Convert Sitecore 8 XHTML Validation from Error to Warning

Tags: validation, sitecore

I am wondering if anyone knows how to convert an convert a Sitecore Validator to display a warning instead of an error. Specifically the Full Page XHTML validation. Basically we want to keep the warning on the page as a CYA and not remove it completely but still allow content editors to proceed.

How would I accomplish this best if possible? Any pointers are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the validation rules under `/sitecore/system/Settings/Validation Rules`.

In the example of Full Page XHTML validation, that would be `/sitecore/system/Settings/Validation Rules/Item Rules/Item/Full Page XHtml`. You can actually edit the `Parameters` field. To change the severity of the validation, add the `Result` parameter, with one of the following values:

- Valid
- Suggestion
- Warning
- Error
- CriticalError
- FatalError

In your example to have the error show as warning, set the `Parameters` field to `Result=Warning`

Note that this change will show everywhere the rule is used (and breached).

Comment: Thanks! Works great!